# Change MutableList during Iteration

Tags: kotlin, iteration, mutablelist

Ok, so. I'm absolutely stumped by this problem. 
I have a function, which sorts a list of objects and gives it back, à la 
1,  1.1,  1.2, 1.2.1,   2, 2.2,   3.

```
fun getFolderHierachy(allFolders: List<FolderEntity>): List<FolderEntity>? {

  //puts the entrypoints( 1, 2, 3) in a list
        if (allFolders.isNotEmpty()) {
            val foldersSorted: MutableList<FolderEntity> = mutableListOf()
            allFolders.forEach {
                if (it.parentDir == null) {
                    foldersSorted.add(it)
                }
            }

// should insert an element, after the matching one ( 1, 1.1, 2, 3) 
            while (foldersSorted.size != allFolders.size) {
                foldersSorted.forEach { parentFolder ->
                    allFolders.forEach {
                        if (!foldersSorted.contains(it)) {
                            if (it.parentDir == parentFolder.uid) {
                                val index = foldersSorted.indexOf(parentFolder)
                                foldersSorted.add(index + 1, it)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            println(foldersSorted)
            return foldersSorted
        }
        return null
    }
```

I know should work, because it already delievered me the correct results. However after the last update from my master, it throws this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.ur.mi.audidroid, PID: 16634
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
        at de.ur.mi.audidroid.viewmodels.FolderViewModel.getFolderHierachy(FolderViewModel.kt:206)
        at de.ur.mi.audidroid.viewmodels.FolderViewModel$initFolderSorting$1.onChanged(FolderViewModel.kt:45)
        at de.ur.mi.audidroid.viewmodels.FolderViewModel$initFolderSorting$1.onChanged(FolderViewModel.kt:20)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:152)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

The update didn't even change anything relevant to this function. I know it hast something to do with the change of the list while iterating, but shouldn't MutableList take care of that? 
I'm so confused at how I should change it to make it work again, please help.

Comment: what does `FolderEntity` look like ? and whats the input that gave the error?

Comment: I'm trying to mimic a folderstructure, with FolderEntity.uid being the primary key and .parentDir being a nullable reference to another FolderEntity.uid. (both Ints).

Comment: The input was something like [name="f_1", uid=1,parentDir=null] [name="f_2", uid=1,parentDir=1] [name="f_3", uid=1,parentDir=null], with f_2 being considered a "subfolder" of f_1. The endgoal is to display my database entries in a sorted manner.

Comment: You can’t add or remove from a list while you’re iterating it with a for loop. You can do it by using the Iterator object directly and calling add and remove on the Iterator. But your code looks quite convoluted. I don’t know exactly what you’re doing but you could probably write a single comparator and apply it to a mutable copy of your allFolders list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `foreach` you use the `List`'s `iterator` which doesn't allow concurrent modification until the loop exists. To get around this, use a standard `for` loop.

```
while (foldersSorted.size != allFolders.size) {
    for (i in 0 until foldersSorted.size) {
        val parentFolder = foldersSorted[i]
        // Rest of code
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good solution if you only need to modify items in-place, but is likely to hit trouble if you add or remove items.  (Appending items is safe if you check the list size each iteration, which that code doesn't.  Or to allow the current item to be removed, the usual solution is to start with the last index, and count down.)  Alternatively, you could iterate through something like a CopyOnWriteArrayList, which would allow changes but not reflect them in the current iteration.